# Overlapping of text shadow

Tags: jquery, html, css

how to make a shadow effect as in the picture, with CSS3?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? This can be as simple as overlaying a transparent gif or png, or using a CSS gradient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linear gradient to achieve this.

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #e05252 0%, #52e0e0 50%, #ffffff 100%);
```

[**Working JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6HTBL/1/)